# Laravel/Public redirect to localhost

Tags: apache, laravel, localhost, wamp

I've imported a project with this path : `C:\wamp64\www\projectName\laravel`

My .htaccess redirect to the laravel/public/ folder :

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^laravel/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]`

And it was okay, I had jus some error with the database but since I've fixed it, it cause me some troubles, because now when i'm on the same url, it redirect me at the wamp homepage

So i found a another .htaccess on path/projectName/laravel/public but i don't know if that interfer with the other .htaccess, maybe ?

`
    
        Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`

I've checked the rewrite_module on apache setting

And the only thing i found is on the log error of appache :

`[Fri Apr 21 11:04:16.781901 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00428: Parent: child process 6444 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:16.822008 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:16.847181 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:16.847682 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:43:51
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:16.847682 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.23\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23'
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:16.849534 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5104
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:17.208634 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 5104:tid 452] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:17.232829 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5104:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:18.311301 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00428: Parent: child process 5104 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:18.347397 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:18.370859 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:18.370859 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:43:51
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:18.370859 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.23\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23'
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:18.373581 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4748
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:18.645510 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 4748:tid 452] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:18.670857 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4748:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:19.729942 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00428: Parent: child process 4748 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:19.763030 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:19.783880 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:19.783880 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:43:51
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:19.783880 2017] [core:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.23\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23'
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:19.785731 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1008
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:20.041074 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1008:tid 420] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:20.065001 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1008:tid 420] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Apr 21 11:04:21.135137 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5284:tid 572] AH00428: Parent: child process 1008 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.`

etc....

Can anyone help me ? I am a little bit noob :(

**EDIT**
httpd-vhosts.conf :

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@hguitare.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp64\www\hguitare\laravel\public"
    ServerName hguitare.dev
    ServerAlias www.hguitare
    ErrorLog "logs/hguitare-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/hguitare-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:\wamp64\www\hguitare\laravel\public">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Did you set virtual host for this project..

Comment: No, What will it do for me ?

Comment: Hey simon try to set host and then check error is comming or not

Comment: You appear to be putting 2 seperate Virtual Hosts inside ONE Virtual Host definition. That wont work, make 2 seperate Virtual Hosts [See thsi for help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: I've just edited my virtual-hosts file, it seems to be ok but it doesn't work.. "Adress not found" can be helped ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this steps to set virtual host (laravel project)

1. Go to this path **C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**
2. Add this settings

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerAdmin webmaster@projectName.dev
>     DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/projectName/public"
>     ServerName projectName.dev
>     ServerAlias www.projectName
>     ErrorLog "logs/projectName-error.log"
>     CustomLog "logs/projectName-access.log" common
>     <Directory "C:/wamp/www/projectName/public">
>       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>       AllowOverride all
>       Order Deny,Allow
>       Deny from all
>       Allow from 127.0.0.1
>     </Directory>   </VirtualHost>
> ```

3. Open hosts file from path **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** (as admin other wise you can not edit this file)
4. Add this line

> ```
>   127.0.0.1  localhost
>   127.0.0.1  projectName.dev
> ```

5. Final step restart your wamp and check (http://projectName.dev/)

Comment: "You don't have permission to access / on this server."
on 127.0.0.1

But i'm not sur how i update httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: I had the content of this file on my question

Comment: He is using `apache2.4.23` so change your answer to use the same version numbers as the OP is using and he may not get so confused

Comment: I said that i don't have access, sorry on 'http://projectName.dev' the url can't be found